# How to select a tabpage based on the tab page TAG value

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, syncfusion

I have a syncfusion tab control and their Tabs are populated according to the number of accounts a user has.

```cs
foreach (SecurityAccount securityAccount in secs)
{
    string name = securityAccount.AccountNumber;

    Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Tools.TabPageAdv tabPage = 
             new Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Tools.TabPageAdv(securityAccount.PortfolioName 
                             + " [" + securityAccount.AccountNumber + "]");

    tabPage.Tag = securityAccount.AccountNumber;
    tcAcc.TabPages.Add(tabPage);

    if (securityAccount.IsDefaultPortfolio)
        defaultPortfolioName = securityAccount.AccountNumber;
}
```

In every security account, there is a field called `IsDefaultPortfolio` Account or a not.
so if it is a default one I am putting that value in the defaultPortfolioName parameter
So now I want to select the tabpage that has this security account number (Which is put into tabPage.Tag value.

I wrote this

```cs
tcAcc.SelectedIndex = tcAcc.TabPages.IndexOf(defaultPortfolioName);
```

But that doesn't work because I am not saying to check the Tag value of each tab.

Answer (score 0):

Select the tabpage based on the value stored in the tag of each tabpage.

```
foreach(TabPageAdv page in tabControlAdv1.TabPages)
{
   if(defaultPortfolioName==(int)page.Tag)
    {
       tabControlAdv1.SelectedIndex = tabControlAdv1.TabPages.IndexOf(page);
        break;
     }
}
```